# Copy Into Upsert/Overwrite

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using the copy into feature and was wondering if there's a way to upsert? I currently have a primary key on a column and when copying another file with matching primary keys it writes a new row in. Is there a way to upsert the original row using the copy into feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from COPY INTO you cannot upsert, but with the [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) command you can, via the SELECT being from the STAGING location, but I am not sure if this avoid duplicate file reads as the COPY provides. We load via COPY into a temporary table, then MERGE into our tables, which allows allows transforming after the load, thus ELT instead of ETL..